# how to check if a key of a record is used in other tables as foreign key (sql)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that its primary key "ID" field is used in many other table as foreign key.

How can I realize that a record from this table (for example first record "ID = 1") is used in other table?

I don't want to select from all other tables to understand it cause tables are so many and relations either. I searched for a solution, there were no working solutions or I got it wrong. Please help.

Comment: What do you need to know this for? To not delete a record if it's being used as a FK? Then set the other tables' foreign keys to be "ON DELETE RESTRICT" instead of "CASCADE". Boom, no more unintentional deletions.

Comment: I have an Isdeleted field that i make it true if any other record use this record's ID as foreign key but if this record's ID isnt used in other tables as foreign key I want to delete it.

Comment: SQL server doesn't support ON DELETE RESTRICT, but you can use ON DELETE NO ACTION to get the desired behavior (an error if you attempt to delete a row that is used by another table as an FK).

Comment: Apply ON DELETE NO ACTION to the FK. Issue the DELETE command; if there is an FK violation error, catch it and set the deleted flag.

Answer (score 9):

For a Generic way use this and you will get all the tables that have the foreign key, and then u can make a loop to check all tables in list. This way u can add foreign keys and no change in code will be needed...

```
SELECT 
sys.sysobjects.name,
sys.foreign_keys.*
FROM 
sys.foreign_keys 
inner join sys.sysobjects on
    sys.foreign_keys.parent_object_id = sys.sysobjects.id
WHERE 
referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]')
```

Comment: Yet simpler code might be: `select object_name(parent_object_id) * from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = object_id('dbo.TableName')`

Answer (score 3):

You *need* to join all other tables. Like this:

```
select *
from Parents
where
 exists(select * from Children1 where ...)
 or exists(select * from Children2 where ...)
 or exists(select * from Children3 where ...)
```

If all your FK columns are indexed this will be extremely efficient. You will get nice merge joins.